# How this program works C?

Tags: c

I found This program is K&R The C programming book I'm new to C programming
I'm not getting why the variable d is used and the value of d is change to d=0
then d=1 between program.

Can anyone explain me what this program logic does I know this program is to replace
tabs with \t likewise.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c, d;

    while ( (c=getchar()) != EOF) {
        d = 0;
        if (c == '\\') {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('\\');
            d = 1;
        }
        if (c == '\t') {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('t');
            d = 1;
        }
        if (c == '\b') {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('b');
            d = 1;
        }
        if (d == 0)
            putchar(c);        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if d remains 0 it has not escaped anything therefore it outputs the read char. An elegant way to avoid if() {} else if () {} else {} construct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`d` is used as a *flag variable* (i.e. a variable that communicates a single binary condition, yes or no). The program sets `d` to one when it has interpreted the character `c` as a special character, and printed its slash-prefixed value. The program checks that `d` flag later on to determine if it has printed `c` or not. If the answer is no, then the program prints `c`; otherwise, it continues to the next iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm ... let's step-by-step

1. say you read an 'G'
2. d is assigned 0
3. none of the 1st 3 `if`s "work"
4. the 'G' is output
5. now you read a tab
6. the 2nd `if` "works"
7. the 2 characters `\` and `t` are output
8. d is assigned 1
9. no more output
10. now you read a single backslash
11. the 1st `if` "works"
12. the 2 characters `\` and `\` are output
13. d is assigned 1
14. no more output
15. &c

Answer (score 0):

The value of 'd' is used to determine if output has already been made, so this line:

```
if (d == 0)
        putchar(c);
```

Is executed when the input is not one of the above. ('\\', '\t', '\b')

Answer (score 0):

it's reading input from user, > one char at a time. and also checking for `escape chars`.

As escapse chars actually contain 2 chars, so within if condition escapse char is printed (2 putchars), which is input by user.

`d` works as a flag to tell that if user entered an escape char.

d == 1 => user entered escape char and it's already printed. don't print again

d == 0 => user entered normal char and it should be printed now.

Note: Other escapse chars also exist but not handled in above program.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a fairly poorly written program. A better version might be written as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;

    while ( (c=getchar()) != EOF) {
        switch (c) {
        case '\\':
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('\\');
            break;
        case '\t':
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('t');
            break;
        case '\b':
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('b');
            break;
        default:
            putchar(c);
        }    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here, the extra variable, `d`, is not needed to keep track of whether or not the program has echoed the input character. It's much easier, I think, to understand what the re-written version does. I'm surprised "The C Programming Language" would feature such a poorly structured program.

Comment: I would not say it's poorly structured, there's a debate on "switch vs if" lasting for at least 3 decades. I guess is just a matter of habit.

Comment: @BigMike: This isn't just a matter of "switch vs if". A series of "if else" would be the alternative to this switch, and yes they'd be more or less equivalent. But the original code doesn't even do that; instead it relies entirely on the compiler being smart enough to elide subsequent comparisons when one of them evaluates to non-zero. If the compiler isn't that smart, then it will be horribly and needlessly inefficient. Not to mention it's harder to understand. I don't think OP would have needed to ask this question had the code been written with a `switch`.

Comment: I can see your point.  I'd rather put those three if into a function and stick a good return statement in place of the assignment. Regarding switch readability I still have my doubt (expecially when thinking about case fallbacks - e.g. Duff Device or similars - those are hard to understand), but that's a completely different matter. Have a nice evening.

Answer (score 0):

simple.

```
while ( (c=getchar()) != EOF) {
```

While C is not the end of file (EOF is code for last character ending a text file), i.e while there are characters to be read on this text file.
Check if c (this character) equal '\' or \t (horizontal tabulation) or \b (backspace). If match, just print it according to my rule and set d as 1.

for all other characters, just print as it is.

```
if (d == 0)     
        putchar(c);
```

How do i know if its a regular charactes? d = 0. When the loop starts again, it sets d as 0 and if one of the 3 specials characters is found, it sets d as 1 again just to prevent it from being printed in the last part one more time.